# Where to aggregate raw data analytics within microservice architecture

Tags: java, architecture, analytics, microservices, aggregation

We need to aggregate analytics for our backoffice. the analytics specs are crossed all over our system where each microservice create it's own raw data. question Where should we aggregate this raw data for analytics purposes: (I thought about two ways)

1. We should create another new service (e.g analytics-service) that will aggregate all the raw data from all services(by push the data to into it) and prepare the aggregations after that having backoffice taking final results
2. Each service will aggregate it's own analytics and our backoffice will send requests (and cache) the aggregated results from all the microservices ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of frameworks and services out there that will do this for you.  Dropwizard, statsd, New Relic, App Dynamics.  Just do some research. I'd say don't roll your own because you'll spend more time creating and adding features to your metrics system than you will be gaining value from it.  Use something out of the box to get up and running quickly with a host of features already developed.

-- Update --

Here are the things I'd look for when deciding on a cross service metrics generation / collection system.

- Minimal to no source code manipulation.  Lots of libraries can inspect runtimes without actually modifying source code.  There are also APIs you can use in conjunction with the instrumentation to add specific metric gathering code if you need it later on.
- Easy collection.  Pointing your metrics gathering services to a collector should be easy to configure.
- Easy viewing / aggregation.  Once you have the metrics collected, it should be easy to see where the data came from, and what the data points are.

Basically, choose one that gets you the most for minimal work.  You may find the base solution will meet your needs.  If not, spend time adding in extra collectors / dashboards.

Comment: but even if I use Dropwizard how Iam going to collect to the metrics and provide them to backoffice ?

Comment: also does Dropwizard does the counts(aka the aggregations)

Comment: Check out the docs.  You can use the reporters to push data to a collector. http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.3/manual/graphite.html

Comment: we thought about using keen.io if you heard about it. what do you think about solutions like that? (e.g dont think they use statsd or dropwizard)

Comment: I haven't looked at keen.io specifically, but updated my answer with what I'd look for in a solution.

Comment: thank you. could you elaborate the point regarding the "collector". what is the collector? diff service that collects all raw data?

Comment: Yeah, such as graphite which I linked to above.  Reporters report to a "collector" service.  Not sure if collector is the standard term, but in concept it is just collecting data points.

Comment: you suggested to use hosted solutions.. i need to maintains graphite if I go this way. any suggestion where I can get it as a service?

Comment: If you google "hosted graphite"  there are a few solutions that pop up in the top 10 results.